# I am using onkeyup function in javascript and If I press key then I get different ASCII value

Tags: javascript, html

I am using onkeyup function in javascript and I think `event.which` give us ascii value of entered character but I am getting different value of entered character. I don't know why it's happening. Please tell me about that.

```html
<input type="text" size="40" onkeyup="myFunction(event)">
<div id="demo"><div>
 <script>
  function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The Unicode value is: " + x;
 }
 </script>
```

If I enter 1 then it shows 91. According to me 48 should come because ASCII value of 1 is 48

[image].

As shown in an image what I am trying to say

Answer (score 1):

`which` is not a Unicode or ASCII character code, it's a keyboard mapping code. `which` is also deprecated, and not as well support as (the also now deprecated) `keyCode`.

The closest thing to what you want (and even this is now deprecated!) is `charCode`. But this only works for `keypress` events, not `keydown` or `keyup`.

What you're now *supposed to* be using these days is `key` -- that's the most recent and non-deprecated way of checking what key has been pressed. The value of `key` might be a name for a key, like "Enter", but if `key` is a string that's just one character in length, then `key.charCodeAt(0)` will give you a character code.

Update: I just double-checked something I wasn't sure about before. The effect of the Shift key is properly reflected in the value you get for `key`.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You wrote when you enter 1 its 91

Your image shows 44

Your thought is 48

its MAGIC !!

Just replace onkeyup="myFunction(event)" with onkeypress="myFunction(event)"

You will get always '49'

Refer the list of ASCII values in HTML (which is 49 for digit 1) https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp

Comment: I got what's matter. I am getting a key code of each key of a keyboard by pressing a key. As you know there is a repetition of a key on a keyboard, such as repetition of integer key, every key has different key codes. that's why I am getting 49 on press key which value has "1" and I am also getting 97 on press key which has the same value as "1". 
Because there are two keys in a keyboard which has the same value as "1".

Comment: I Didn't even notice that I press the "print screen" key after press "1". so that's why I am getting 44 because 44 is a key code of print screen. and Yes you are right 49 should come on press key "1". and In case of 91 I pressed another key(I do not remember) after pressing "1". so I am getting 91.

Comment: So i guess, you must accept an answer to close this question . Isn't it ??

Comment: I got an answer and found out why this was happening.